# Are there any good solutions for javascript drawing on github pages and markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-pages, visio

I want to publish visio like pictures on github pages in README.md. for now I upload visio png files, since it's binary files, it cost lots of storage.

since I use MathJax for formula on README.md, I want javascript solutions to replace visio binary pictures.

Comment: "cost lots of storage"... really?

Comment: @mb21 i mean, every modify of the visio will change png file, binary file use more storage in git.

Answer (score 0):

you could give a try to my Visio export - it can publish SVG version of the Visio diagram as a github page (free for personal use).

http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/
[image]
Feel free to contact me directly as well :)